# 3 column layout but hide the middle column

Tags: html, css, angular, layout, multiple-columns

I'm doing Angular project and I was wondering if there is a way to make three CSS column but hiding the middle column at the beginning when the page is open and only show up the middle column when the user entered any information that matched in the search box.

little bit more details here

- At the beginning the black color column will take about 70% of the page and red will be the remaining 30% (picture)
- When the user input any information in the search box, Black and Yellow column will take about 40% each and red column will be the 20% of the remaining page. (picture)

[This is what it'll look like when the page is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDLUo.png)

[This is what it'll look like user enter any information in the search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXySz.png)

I'm not sure if the 3 column layout can be done using just HTML and CSS but any suggestion will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you .ts file
Get the results from API and store as a variable called the result

```
this.result = ['result1','result2'] // may be array or json
```

If you using bootstrap in your angular project it is very easy, like this

```
<div class="maindiv row col-md-12">
    <div [ngClass]="[result.length ? 'col-md-5' : 'col-md-6']">
        information 1
    </div>
    <div [ngClass]="[result.length ? 'col-md-5' : 'd-none']">
        car pic 1 and 2 (results)
    </div>
    <div [ngClass]="[result.length ? 'col-md-2' : 'col-md-6']">
        information 2
    </div>    
</div>
```

otherwise, you need to write manual class, like this

```
<div class="maindiv row">
    <div [ngClass]="[result.length ? 'w-40' : 'w-50']">
        information 1
    </div>
    <div [ngClass]="[result.length ? 'w-40' : 'd-none']">
        car pic 1 and 2 (results)
    </div>
    <div [ngClass]="[result.length ? 'w-20' : 'w-50']">
        information 2
    </div>    
</div>
```

finally .css files if you are not using bootstrap

```
.w-40
{
    width:40%;
}
.w-50
{
    width:50%;
}
.w-20
{
    width:20%;
}
.d-none
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen. by any chance, do you know how not to display the middle column even there is data on the list. Right I need to removed the data first if I don't want to display the middle column.

Answer (score 0):

bind your search input with variable. let's say filterText:any = '';
hide middle column/div when the filterText is empty.

```
<div [hidden]="filterText.length<1"></div>
```